# Eye of Gnome - Open two images on different windows with shell script

Tags: c++, shell

It might sound like a stupid question by I'm trying to work this out for a while but I can't figure out how to solve it.

I have two images named `imagem.bmp` and `imagem2.bmp` and a shell script that is supposed to open these two images using eye of gnome. I have written this in the script:

```
#!/usr/bash
eog imagem.bmp
eog imagem2.bmp
```

The problem is that only one image is opened, i.e., eog opens the first image and then the second image is loaded in the same screen. All I need is to open it in two separate screens so that i can compare the images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help text is always useful:

```
$ eog --help
Usage:
  eog [OPTION...] [FILE…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                         Show help options
  --help-all                         Show all help options
  --help-gtk                         Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -f, --fullscreen                   Open in fullscreen mode
  -c, --disable-image-collection     Disable image collection
  -s, --slide-show                   Open in slideshow mode
  -n, --new-instance                 Start a new instance instead of reusing an existing one
  --version                          Show the application's version
  --display=DISPLAY                  X display to use
```

Notice this option:

```
-n, --new-instance       Start a new instance instead of reusing an existing one
```

Instead of running `eog`, run `eog -n` to open a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` waits for one command to finish executing before starting another. You can use `&` to execute a program "in the background". Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
eog imagem.bmp &
eog imagem2.bmp &
```

I also fixed the `/usr/bash` bug.

Strictly speaking, the second line doesn't need the `&`, but this will return your prompt to you faster, without waiting for the second `eog` process to terminate.